# MS Access in Query Sort By Missing Records - Bug?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a query that displays data from one linked table and when I execute the query I get 1852 records. However, it only returns 198 records upon immediate execution (this is what I can visually see when selecting the last record). Only when I arrow down or go to the end of the recordset (Ctrl+end) the query actually shows all 1852 records.

The issue I am having is when I select the order by a-z or z-a **BEFORE** arrowing down or going to the end of the recordset it sorts the records by only the initial 198 it displays.

If I select arrow down or go to the end of the records **BEFORE** selecting the order by option, the query sorts and displays **ALL** 1852 records.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be great.

I also want to point out that this does not happen if I am linked to an Access back end table, only my SQL Server back end table.

Answer (score 0):

Access and the ODBC driver only pulls the record needed to fill the display, at least for a start.

Try expanding the query a bit by adding a simple *filter* or *sorting*, like:

```
 Where [SomeField] Is Not Null
```

and/or:

```
 Order By [SomeField]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The query is already filtered by a date range. I am not sure modifying my query results is the solution either.

Comment: Perhaps not. But I can't replicate your scenario, so I have no solution.